# Blurring a specific text in a column of multiple texts in . In this case I want to blur pin so that there will be a button to switch blurring

Tags: flutter

Column(
children: [
Text('username'),

```
                      Text('pin')),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageFiltered-class.html for blur your `Text` widget.

import `import 'dart:ui';`

```
Column(children: [
       Text('username'),
       ImageFiltered(
          imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
          child: Text('pin'))
])
```